# How can I remove every chars and symbol from a string beside of number and semicolon in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I remove every chars and symbol from a string beside of number and semicolon in javascript?

Example:
If i have a string below:

```
test = 'jfh345;54dfg5dfg@@#';
```

how can I remove every chars and symbol from the string beside of number and semicolon and the output like below after the remove:

'345;545'

Comment: use a regex. What have you tried?

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

Replace anything that is not number or semicolon.

```
test = 'jfh345;54dfg5dfg@@#';

res = test.replace(/[^\d;]+/g, '');
```

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wY0aW3/1)

Comment: The demo replaces punctuation with spaces,  if you don't want spaces in the output use:  **test.replace(/[^\d;]+/g, "");**

Comment: @ArifBurhan That is just the indication of what is replaced.